# Website in ASP.NET using Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net

Is it legal to develop a ASP.NET and C#.NET website using Visual Studio 2010 Standard or Express edition? or do i have to buy some licence? This website will contain commercial ads for money making.

Answer (score 3):

So long as you're not using pirated software then it's perfectly legal.

Comment: Thanks. Express edition is for free download. Now is it legal?

Comment: @sun1 so long as you get it direct from microsoft then you're good.